# Android: SwipeRefreshLayout will not call OnRefresh()

Tags: java, android, xml, refresh, swiperefreshlayout

This community has proven very helpful for my personal and school projects, so I have decided to join.  This is my first question.  Currently I am building an Android application during my free time in the summer.  I am trying to implement a SwipeRefreshLayout in one of my application's fragments, but for unknown reasons, I cannot seem to get my fragment to call the OnRefresh() method when I pull to refresh.

Here is my Java code:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Notifications extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener{
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    private View view;

    public Notifications() {

    }

    public static Notifications newInstance() {
        Notifications fragment = new Notifications();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        accessDataBase();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeColors(android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_red_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_blue_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        Log.d("Notifications", "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");
    }

    // Used to access my Parse Server database
    public void accessDataBase() {
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("OurPushes");
        query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_THEN_NETWORK);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    List<String> subject = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<String> body = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (ParseObject pushObject : objects) {
                        if(pushObject.getString("title") != "")
                            subject.add(pushObject.getString("title"));
                        else
                            subject.add("");
                        if(pushObject.getString("alert") != "")
                            body.add(pushObject.getString("alert"));
                        else
                            body.add("");
                    }

                    Collections.reverse(subject);
                    Collections.reverse(body);

                    if(getActivity() != null) {
                        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(subject, body);
                        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rv);
                        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    Log.d("Brand", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Here is my XML code (fragment_notifications.xml):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And here are the results on my Android Monitor.  Notice my Log.d statement within OnRefresh() was not called despite me pulling to refresh on my Android device:

```
06-16 17:57:13.022 2668-2668/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-16 17:57:13.314 2668-2718/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-16 17:57:13.317 2668-2668/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx D/Atlas: Validating map...
06-16 17:57:13.353 2668-2718/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx I/Adreno: EGLInit: QTI Build: 03/04/15, eeab148, 
06-16 17:57:13.365 2668-2718/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-16 17:57:13.366 2668-2718/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx I/Adreno: GetNativeFormatFromQctPixelFormat: Invalid qct format (611)
06-16 17:57:13.366 2668-2718/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx I/Adreno: GetNativeFormatFromQctPixelFormat: Invalid qct format (611)
06-16 17:57:13.366 2668-2718/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx I/Adreno: GetNativeFormatFromQctPixelFormat: Invalid qct format (611)
06-16 17:57:13.366 2668-2718/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx I/Adreno: GetNativeFormatFromQctPixelFormat: Invalid qct format (611)
06-16 17:57:13.366 2668-2718/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx I/Adreno: GetNativeFormatFromQctPixelFormat: Invalid qct format (612)
06-16 17:57:13.366 2668-2718/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx I/Adreno: GetNativeFormatFromQctPixelFormat: Invalid qct format (612)
06-16 17:57:13.366 2668-2718/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx I/Adreno: GetNativeFormatFromQctPixelFormat: Invalid qct format (612)
06-16 17:57:13.366 2668-2718/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx I/Adreno: GetNativeFormatFromQctPixelFormat: Invalid qct format (612)
06-16 17:57:13.373 2668-2718/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
06-16 17:57:13.394 2668-2668/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-16 17:57:13.445 2668-2719/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx I/OpenGLRenderer: WorkerThread::readyToRun:hwuiTask1
06-16 17:58:46.962 2668-4140/xxxxxxx.xxxxxx I/OpenGLRenderer: WorkerThread::readyToRun:hwuiTask2
```

And I know some of you may mention, I know Parse is nearing end life.  I am using Parse Server.  My parse server is hosted on Heroku, not Parse.com.

Thanks in advance for your help.  If you'd like any additional information, please ask.

Comment: hey men `pushObject.getString("title") != ""` this not working.. because comparate Strings u need a equals("yourtext").. is better if use isEmpty()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In onCreateView you are returning a different view to the one you set up with the OnRefreshListener. Notice you have called `inflater.inflate(...)` twice, creating two separate Views. Try this instead:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    accessDataBase();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);
    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeLayout.setColorSchemeColors(android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_red_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_blue_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);
    return view;

}
```

Comment: That was a great observation!

Comment: this line is important, most of us missed this

 `swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);`